# Is it true that mocks also fail or are unable to do TDD tests with database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, unit-testing, mocking

In theory, it is difficult to perform tests on functional code bases that need interactions with database, but I think we can use mocks. In real life applications, do you have failed cases when applying mocks to perform TDD tests with databases ? Could you shared some thoughts to explain this to me?

Comment: Please, explain further. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tdd i use mocks to replace the physical database access with a fake (mock).

For databaseaccess i am always using a [The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) as api which can be easily mocked.

To Answer your question:

```
> do you have failed cases when applying mocks 
> to perform TDD tests with databases ?
```

**No** as long all database-operations are encapsulated in the repository.

Comment: Thank you, my knowledge is still too limited and still unable to handle crackpots'ideas. I would have shamed my online professor if I call her my online professor. Sorry.